# What does void do/mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript, and I came across this switch statement in a tutorial. I know that number is assigned to a, so all parameters should be numbers.  But, what does void mean and do?

```
function switchFunction(a: number): void {
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            let variableInCase1 = "test";
            console.log(variableInCase1);
            break;
        case 2:
            let variableInCase2 = "test2";
            console.log(variableInCase2);
            break;
        default:
          console.log("Default");    
    }
}
switchFunction(1);
switchFunction(2);
switchFunction(3);
```

Comment: If you want your function to do an operation and after it will returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the function is not expecting a return value, evident in the fact that there is no `return` statement. In other words, the function can only equate to `null` or `undefined`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void